# How to avoid nesting in a XML AUTO query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Customer.CustomerID,
    OtherContact.PersonID,
    [External].ExternalID,
    [External].ExternalSource
FROM dbo.v_Customer Customer (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_CustomerOtherContact OtherContact (NOLOCK) ON Customer.CustomerID = OtherContact.CustomerID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerExternalIdentifier [External] (NOLOCK) ON [External].CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = 11553408
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

The output is a bit perplexing as it places the result of the second join inside the first join:

```
<Customer>
    <CustomerID>11553408</CustomerID>
    <OtherContact>
        <External>
            <ExternalID>master-account</ExternalID>
            <ExternalSource>suis</ExternalSource>
        </External>
    </OtherContact>
</Customer>
```

What I want instead is the following:

```
<Customer>
    <CustomerID>11553408</CustomerID>
    <OtherContact></OtherContact>
    <External>
        <ExternalID>master-account</ExternalID>
        <ExternalSource>suis</ExternalSource>
    </External>
</Customer>
```

Is it possible to get the output above with XML AUTO?

Comment: I suspect `FOR XML PATH` might be a better option for you. What is with `NOLOCK`, it's like an incantation or something, **why do you use it when [it's so full of issues](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)?**

Comment: Can you add the table definition and insert script ? It is easier to work on this if I get those. Thanks

Comment: @Charlieface Most of these issues don't apply to my situation, other than uncommitted reads.  But mostly because it's a giant DB upgraded through the ages from SQL 2000 to 2005 to 2008 to 2014, etc...  Without NOLOCK, deadlocks are all over the place.  So the price for uncommitted reads is cheaper than having to re-architect an entire database.